# WriteToStreamAsync cancel does not work

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, .net-4.5, filestream, windows-10-universal

I am running a Task, which copies from one stream to another. This works without problems, including progress reporting. But i cant cancel the task. If i fire the CancellationToken, the copy progress runs till its completion, then the task is cancelled, but this is of course to late. Here is my actual code

```
private async Task Download(Uri uriToWork, CancellationToken cts)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage requestAction = new HttpRequestMessage();
    requestAction.Method = new HttpMethod("GET");
    requestAction.RequestUri = uriToWork;

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseContent = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(requestAction, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

    using (Stream streamToRead = (await httpResponseContent.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync()).AsStreamForRead())
    {
        string fileToWrite = Path.GetTempFileName();
        using (Stream streamToWrite = File.Open(fileToWrite, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await httpResponseContent.Content.WriteToStreamAsync(streamToWrite.AsOutputStream()).AsTask(cts, progressDownload); 

            await streamToWrite.FlushAsync();
            //streamToWrite.Dispose();
         }

         await streamToRead.FlushAsync();
         //streamToRead.Dispose();
    }
    httpClient.Dispose();
}
```

Can someone help me please, or can explain, why it does not work?

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you are passing in your `CancellationToken`?

Comment: Also, you have a using statement, you don't need to dispose, that's what the using statement does for you.

Comment: I have updated my Code, to Show the entire Task with the token which i pass in.

Comment: Is there not an overload of `WriteToStreamAsync` that directly accepts a cancellation token?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: As-written, that can't be your real code.  Minimally, there's no semicolon at the end of `HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()`, so it'll fail to compile.

Comment: Sure its my real code, the semicolon i have forget, because i cleaned my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it this operation that continues until it completes ?

```
await httpResponseContent.Content.WriteToStreamAsync(streamToWrite.AsOutputStream()).AsTask(cts, progressDownload);
```

Or is it this one ?

```
await streamToWrite.FlushAsync();
```

I think the latter needs probably to have the CancellationToken as well:

```
await streamToWrite.FlushAsync(cts);
```

Unfortunately I cannot answer why this cancel does not occur. However, a solution that consists in **writing the Stream in chunks** may help.

---

Here is something *very* dirty that works:

```
private async Task Download(Uri uriToWork, CancellationToken cts) {

    using(HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()) {

        HttpRequestMessage requestAction = new HttpRequestMessage();
        requestAction.Method = new HttpMethod("GET");
        requestAction.RequestUri = uriToWork;

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseContent = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(requestAction, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        string fileToWrite = Path.GetTempFileName();
        using(Stream streamToWrite = File.Open(fileToWrite, FileMode.Create)) {

            // Disposes streamToWrite to force any write operation to fail
            cts.Register(() => streamToWrite.Dispose());

            try {
                await httpResponseContent.Content.WriteToStreamAsync(streamToWrite.AsOutputStream()).AsTask(cts, p);
            }
            catch(TaskCanceledException) {
                return; // "gracefully" exit when the token is cancelled
            }

            await streamToWrite.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

- I enclosed the `httpClient` in a `using` so a `return` disposes it properly.
- I removed the `streamToRead` which was not used at all
- Now here is the horror: I added a delegate that executes when the token is cancelled: it disposes `streamToWrite` while it is written to (ughhhh), which triggers an `TaskCancelledException` when WriteToStreamAsync cannot longer write in this disposed stream.

Please dont throw a puke bag at me yet, I am not experienced enough in this "Universal" Framework which looks very different as the usual one.

Here is a chunked stream solution that looks more acceptable. I shortened a bit the original code and added the IProgress as a parameter.

---

```
async Task Download(Uri uriToWork, CancellationToken cts, IProgress<int> progress) {
    using(HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()) {

        var chunkSize = 1024;
        var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
        int count = 0;
        string fileToWrite = Path.GetTempFileName();

        using(var inputStream = await httpClient.GetInputStreamAsync(uriToWork)) {
            using(var streamToRead = inputStream.AsStreamForRead()) {
                using(Stream streamToWrite = File.OpenWrite(fileToWrite)) {
                    int size;
                    while((size = await streamToRead.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, chunkSize, cts).ConfigureAwait(false)) > 0) {
                        count += size;
                        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => progress.Report(count));
                        // progress.Report(count);
                        await streamToWrite.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, size, cts).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the first Operation you wrote, which does not cancel.

I pass the CancellationToken on the Task call and pass it.

Comment: Aw gosh. And there is no WriteToStreamAsync signature that accept a CancellationToken.

Comment: And the progressreport works fine... Hm. Could you please check the CancellationToken status as you cancel it outside? Just to check if you are actually cancelling the right CancellationSource that is attached to the token you pass.

Comment: Yes. I updated my code with the complete task call. Is there any other solution, to cancel it? It doesnt need to be the WriteToStreamAsync method.

Comment: I have checked that. If i cancel the task, it runs until the end, but the stream isnt wrote completely, so the destination file does not contain the content. Shortly before i receive a TaskCancelledException on "await httpResponseContent.Content.WriteToStreamAsync(streamToWrite.AsOutputStream()).AsTask(cts, progressDownload);"

Comment: Nobody can help me?:(

Comment: What about performing the Stream copy in chunks, so cancellation occurs a bit quicker?

Comment: By the way, what is streamToRead used for? It looks being useless as it is read once as an async input Stream, then flushed and disposed.

Comment: I didnt work with streams so far. Thats why i dont know how to handle it the right way.

Comment: I came up with something dirty that works. I feel ashamed.

Comment: Thank you for the update. As a temporary solution, it is ok. But i am very interested about an implementation with a chunked stream, if this is possible.

Comment: Here is one. Hope it helps, this Universal Framework is a mess :(

Comment: It works yes, thank you. But i have a really weird behavior. The whole UI is very laggy at the time of transferring. The progressbar is only updating, if i move the mouse Cursor and the rest of the UI isnt really usable. I dont know whats the Problem, im calling the Task with the await Operator, so the work should be asynchronous and dont block the UI thread.

Comment: Oops I probably assumed wrongly that a Dispatcher invocation is done in the IProgress implementation as I did in my test project. Please try to enclose the progress.Report() call with a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(). I will update this a bit later because I am out right now.

Comment: Here it is. I added some ConfigureAwait(false) to ensure continuation does not returns back to the caller thread, and uses Dispatcher.RunAsync in the progress.Report call. I hope that will fix the lagging issue.

Comment: I made some Tests with different file sizes, it works perfectly! I think this is exactly what i searched. Thank you very much for the great help, Larry!

Answer (score 0):

The blocking operation is most probably not `WriteToStreamAsync()` but `FlushAsync()`, so @Larry's assumption should be right, the `FlushAsync` method needs the cancellation token as well.